# Generate new secret_key_base for rails production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I like security, is there anyway to create a new secret_key_base every time I push my Rails app to production? My app will be living on multiple servers, I feel as though each instance should have its own secret_key_base.

Comment: That might affect the password hashing if you're using the `secret_key_base` for something like `devise`. I think it might be better to manually generate a new one for each new instance and leave it like that unless it has been compromised.

Comment: Your `secret_key_base` generally needs to be the same for all running instances of your application. It is used for things like encrypting session cookies or generating other encryption or signing keys in use by your app. If you use different values here, a lot of things will very likely break.